# How to return ajax Response with python HTTPServer?

Tags: python, jquery, python-3.x, ajax, http

I create a sample http server in python,and trying to connect it with ajax post method.
when the client start post,I got `connection ajax from:...` log in my server and than `send_response(200)`,
but in my client part,there always got error and response['status'] = 0,please help me,very thanks!

**HTTPServer part:**(python)

```
class ajax_server(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_POST(self):
        print('connection ajax from:', self.address_string())
        data={"data":"test"}
        json_string = json.dumps(data)
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header(
            'Content-type',
            'application/json'
        )
        self.end_headers()
        self.wfile.write(json_string.encode(encoding='utf-8'))
server = ThreadedHTTPServer("my server ip", ajax_server)
server.serve_forever()
```

**Client part:**(javascript)

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        update_ajax();
        function update_ajax() {    
            $.ajax({
                url: "my server url",
                type: 'POST',
                success: function (response) {
                    alert(response["status"]);
                },
                error: function (response) {
                    alert(response['status']);
                }
            })
            //setTimeout(update_ajax, 1000);
        }  
    });
```

> update:
>
> 1. this server can past json data to chrome browser
> 2. this client works well with django JsonResponse return (response['status'] = 200)
>
> there must some mistake I ignore to create an ajax Response like django does.

Comment: Figure out if the issue is client side (using known working end-point) or server side (use a working client like curl).  Eliminate the working part from the question, and provide output from  the defective part.

Comment: @AllanWind Please do not vote to close questions simply because they are not to your liking. If you read the rules - you will see this type of behavior is noted in the community guidelines.

Comment: @AlanSTACK I voted to close the question because it lacks focus (here is a client in javascript and server in python figure out why it doesn't work).  It has nothing to with me "liking" the question.  In fact, I hope op reworks it as requested, and provide some debug data.

Comment: @AlanSTACK can you kindly shoot me a link to the guideline you are referring to?  I appreciate you pointing out if I am in the wrong here.

Comment: thanks for advise,i provide more detail what I have try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally,I found to add `Access-Control` in header and it works~

```
def do_POST(self):
    print('connection ajax from:', self.address_string())
    data={"data":"test","status":200}
    json_string = json.dumps(data)
    self.send_response(200)
    self.send_header("Content-type", "application/json") 
    self.send_header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*") 
    self.send_header("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin") 
    self.send_header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept") 
    self.end_headers() 
    self.wfile.write(json_string.encode(encoding='utf-8'))
```